# Convert which() to logical vector

Tags: r

I want to create a vector of 0's and 1's such that all elements in y that are 4 become 1 and all other values become 0. `which(y == 4)` returns the indices in y that are 4, and then `y[which(y == 1)]` returns a vector of all 4's. How would I produce a vector of 1's where they were 4's and 0's otherwise?

```
x <- y[which(y == 4)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use logical coercion:

```
as.integer(y==4)
```

The shorter version:

```
+(y==4)
```